# In a bootstrap sample, what is the probability that the 5th observation is the same as the 1st observation?

Tags: probability, bootstrap

I know that the probability of jth observation being in a sample is:

***p(jth obs in bootstrap sample) = (1 - 1/n) ^ n***
***p(5) = (1 - 1/n)^n***
***p(3) = (1 - 1/n)^n***

Can you give me a hint on how to go about solving this? Thank you

Comment: Hint: how does bootstrapping select samples?

Comment: they're selected randomly

Comment: Another hint.  The first observation can be anything.

Comment: "Randomly" means almost nothing.  The key is that they are selected *with equal probabilities* and *with replacement.*  Therein lies the answer.